# How to fix FileReader error where getCause points to null when reading csv file?

Tags: java, csv, filereader

I am testing csv file reading and I keep getting the same error. The error displayed is "Could not read the requested file. Cause: null". This is a dumbed down version of my code that still produces the same error.

```java
public class PersonReader {
    public static List<Person> readPersons(String path) throws IOException{
        ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
            String line = null; // read first line

            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                persons.add(new Person(line));
            }
        } finally {
            if(reader != null) {
                reader.close();
            }
        }

        return persons;
}

public class Person {
    private String name;

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Person> persons = null;

        try {
            persons = PersonReader.readPersons("sample/Data.csv");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not read the requested file. Cause: " + e.getCause());
        }

        if(persons == null) { // some error has occurred
            System.exit(1);
        }

        System.out.println(persons);
    }
}
```

Alternative version of the PersonReader I tried that produces the same error

```java
public class PersonReader {
    public static List<Person> readPersons(String path) throws IOException{
        ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(path));
            String line = null;

            while((line=reader.readLine()) != null) {
                persons.add(new Person(line));
            }
        } finally {
            if(reader != null) {
                reader.close();
            }
        }

        return persons;
    }
```

StackTrace produced

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException:   (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:219)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:112)
    at java.base/java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:60)
    at sample.PersonReader.readPersons(PersonReader.java:17)
    at sample.Main.main(Main.java:14)
```

Comment: put an `e.printStackTrace()` under your catch clause and share the output with us

Comment: I'm sorry I dont know where my head was. I edited the post.

Comment: Why is there no file path in your exception? Is the path empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced `System.err.println("Could not read the requested file. Cause: " + e.getCause());` with `e.printStackTrace()` to get this:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: sample/Data.csv (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
    at xxx.yyy.zzz.PersonReader.readPersons(A.java:37)
    at xxx.yyy.zzz.A.main(A.java:73)
```

Issue is that `FileReader` cannot find the file using its relative path - there's no file "sample/Data.csv" relative to the current working directory. Either you can provide the absolute path or if you can add the file in your project resources, you can do something like this:

```java
  InputStream inputStream = PersonReader.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("sample/Data.csv");
  InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
```

Comment: The error message you get is local to your system.  The OP might/will get a different error message.  And FileReader will most definitely take a relative path.

Comment: Yes. I think I framed the statement wrong - I've tried to fix that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, an `Exception` is a sub-class of a `Throwable`.  The `Throwable.getCause()` method returns "the throwable that caused this throwable to get thrown" (according to the Javadoc).  This can often be `null`.

Instead, call `Throwable.getMessage()`, this "[r]eturns the detail message string of this throwable".